# Removing local storage item with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm working on a simple to-do list with vanilla js. I've managed to add the input to local storage, but have not been able to add the style changes(check strike through) to local storage, nor can I figure out how to remove one item at a time from storage. I have been able to clear all, just unable to remove each item separately. Below is my code, any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
//local storage setup
let saved = window.localStorage.getItem(input.value);

if (saved) {
    list.innerHTML = saved;
}

//handle input submit
function handleSubmitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let input = document.querySelector('input');
    if (input.value != '') {
        addTodo(input.value);
    }
    input.value = '';
    window.localStorage.setItem(input.value, list.innerHTML);
}

//check off todo
function checkTodo(e) {
    let item = e.target.parentNode;
    if (item.style.textDecoration == 'line-through') {
        item.style.textDecoration = 'none';
    } else {
        item.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
    }
    window.localStorage.setItem(item);
}

//delete todo
function deleteTodo(e) {
    let item = e.target.parentNode;
    item.addEventListener('transitionend', function () {
        item.remove();
    });
    item.classList.add('todo-list-item-fall');
    window.localStorage.removeItem(item);
}
```

Comment: when you setItem you're adding a var name then value (```localStorage.setItem("name", "value")```), and if you want to remove the localStorage item, remove it by name (```localStorage.removeItem("name")```).

Comment: Should value still refer to list.innerHTML or should I be referencing the list item a different way? I still can't seem to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

[JavaScript Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) is a key-value pair. Just use a string-based key so you can remove, edit or read it easily.

```js
// Set todo item
localStorage.setItem("todo1", "Stand-up meeting 9.15am");
// Read todo item
localStorage.getItem("todo1");
// Delete todo item
localStorage.removeItem("todo1");
```

It's better if you can save it as a [JSON string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) because you can mark it as completed without delete, so you can find completed tasks too.

```js
// Saving todo item as a JSON string
localStorage.setItem("todo1", JSON.stringify({ text: "Stand-up meeting 9.15am", completed: false }));

// Read it
const todo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todo1"));

// You can read the text
console.log(todo.text);
// Also you can mark it as completed and save it back
todo.completed = true;
localStorage.setItem("todo1", JSON.stringify(todo));
```

Comment: Would this mean assigning input.value and list.innerHTML both to a variable first and then referencing the variable name instead?

Comment: @jsdev Yes, You can have a structure like `{value: input.value, html: list.innerHTML }`

Answer (score 0):

Storing object in localStorage is a tricky job.

Everything you store in the local or session storage is of type `string`

you can create an object like

```
item = {
  value : ANY_VALUE
}
```

and save it in your localStorage using `JSON.stringify`

`` localStorage.setItem(`item`,JSON.stringify(item)) ``

now when you want to update the item just update the object and again set using the ablove syntax

To access the saved item from the local storage use `JSON.parse`

````
yourItemObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem())```
````

You can access values now using `yourItemObject .value`

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're passing the whole `HTML element` (it passed as an object) inside the removeItem function. you need to pass the `key` instead.

 try 
 localStorage.removeItem(item.innerText);

Comment: Thank you, I did try this but unfortunately it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with lists in localStorage. I would use something like this basic example:

```js
function addTodo(key, item){
      var list = getTodo(key);

      list.push(item);

      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(list) );
}

function getTodo(key){

    try{
        var rawList = localStorage.getItem(key);
        return JSON.parse(rawList) || [];
    }
    catch(e){
        return [];
    }
}

function removeTodo(key, id){
  
  var list = getTodo(key);

  var newlist = list.filter( function(item){
      return item.id != id;
  });

  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(newlist) )

}

function emptyTodo(key){
    localStorage.removeItem(key);    
}

addTodo('list', {
    id: 1,
    text: 'do shopping'
});

addTodo('list', {
    id: 2,
    text: 'study'
});

console.log( getTodo('list') );

removeTodo('list', 1);

console.log( getTodo('list') )

emptyTodo('list');
```